# How do I remove a directory recursively?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directory

[`RemoveDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-removedirectorya) removes only empty directories. How do I remove directories that have files inside?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are prepared to use the Windows API then the easiest way to get this done is to call [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164.aspx). Use the `FO_DELETE` operation and don't forget to double null-terminate your directory name.

Comment: Keep in mind that SHFileOperation works great for User Mode applications but does not work when called from a Windows Service, especially if Impersonation is being utilized to remove a directory on a UNC network share.

For this scenario you'll need to do the grunt work and use FindFirstFile()/FindNext() with DeleteFile()/RemoveDirectory() the hard way

Answer (score 14):

Since C++17, the best solution is [`std::filesystem::remove_all`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove). Before that, you can use the Boost implementation, [`boost::filesystem::remove_all`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#remove_all). Either way, you don't have to worry about the platform-specific stuff.

I'm not aware of any other platform-independent solution; the usual way otherwise would involve reading the directory, and recursively descending it (but the way to read the directory also uses `std::filesystem`, `boost::filesystem`, or system-dependent code).

Answer (score 3):

Typically, if no library method is available, this is done by recursion.  A function iterates all directory entries, deleting 'ordinary' files and calling itself with any directory path found.  This destroys whole directory trees, (my Windows version has explicit checks on the path passed to prevent it destroying OS folders in case of accidentally passing in a suicidal parameter).

Answer (score 3):

According to MSDN, `SHFileOperation` is not thread safe when used with relative paths. It can only be safely used with absolute paths.

I recommend using this code instead:

```
double directory_delete(char *pathname)
{
    string str(pathname);
    if (!str.empty())
    {
        while (*str.rbegin() == '\\' || *str.rbegin() == '/')
        {
            str.erase(str.size()-1);
        }
    }
    replace(str.begin(),str.end(),'/','\\');

    struct stat sb;
    if (stat((char *)str.c_str(),&sb) == 0 &&
        S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode))
    {
            HANDLE hFind;
            WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;

            TCHAR DirPath[MAX_PATH];
            TCHAR FileName[MAX_PATH];

            _tcscpy(DirPath,(char *)str.c_str());
            _tcscat(DirPath,"\\*");
            _tcscpy(FileName,(char *)str.c_str());
            _tcscat(FileName,"\\");

            hFind = FindFirstFile(DirPath,&FindFileData);
            if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return 0;
            _tcscpy(DirPath,FileName);

            bool bSearch = true;
            while (bSearch)
            {
                if (FindNextFile(hFind,&FindFileData))
                {
                    if (!(_tcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName,".") &&
                        _tcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName,".."))) continue;
                    _tcscat(FileName,FindFileData.cFileName);
                    if ((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes &
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
                    {
                        if (!directory_delete(FileName))
                        {
                            FindClose(hFind);
                            return 0;
                        }
                        RemoveDirectory(FileName);
                        _tcscpy(FileName,DirPath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes &
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY)
                            _chmod(FileName, _S_IWRITE);

                        if (!DeleteFile(FileName))
                        {
                            FindClose(hFind);
                            return 0;
                        }
                        _tcscpy(FileName,DirPath);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
                        bSearch = false;
                    else
                    {
                        FindClose(hFind);
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            FindClose(hFind);

            return (double)(RemoveDirectory((char *)str.c_str()) == true);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If you want to use my code "as-is", you will need these headers at the top of your cpp file:

```
#include <windows.h> // winapi
#include <sys/stat.h> // stat
#include <tchar.h> // _tcscpy,_tcscat,_tcscmp
#include <string> // string
#include <algorithm> // replace

using namespace std;
```

...and I think that's it.

My code is based on this article:

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/files/folderdirectorymaintenance/article.php/c8999/Deleting-a-Directory-Along-with-SubFolders.htm

I strongly recommend to never use `SHFileOperation`; aside from safety issues, it was replaced by `IFileOperation` since Windows Vista.

Answer (score 2):

This may be lame, but consider using

```
system("rd /s /q ...");
```

It's ugly, but it's too simple to ignore. It also has all the "how to deal with files on network shares" stuff worked out. Whatever solution you come up with is probably an (incomplete and/or incorrect) reimplementation of `rd`, so calling out to the external process would actually be nice code reuse. ;-)

Comment: Code reuse and unportability with not even a compile error if rd does not exist. For a very small program, this might be useful and right, for long life big ones, less. Personally, I would always check if that command actually exists.

Comment: @phresnel: The question is for Windows systems only, and 'rd' is available on all Windows systems by default. I'd go out on a limb and claim that 'rd' being available is more likely than `SHFileOperation` being available (`SHFileOperation` has only been around since Windows XP, and it has been deprecated with Windows Vista).

Comment: The probability is less relevant to me. Personally, I wan't a compile time error if some functionality isn't there; with system you never ever have compile time errors. As said, for small, system specific programs, this might be okay. But I would advice against it for larger or long lived programs. You never know what's in 5, 10, 15 years from now. If suddenly everybody would have switched to Mac or Linux, then surely you would want your cash cow run on that platform, too.

Comment: @phresnel: Well the probability should be highly relevant to you, because it determines whether a solution is good enough. Striving for a "perfect" solution may be wasted effort because you're anticipating problems nobody has (or will have). So it's indeed all about probabilities!

Comment: But if I make it fail upon compilation, then the probability of that regression going unrecognized is 0%, whereas with `system()`, it is somewhere between 1% and 100%. I always strive to develop code that either runs or that doesn't. Half running programs are a real pain to debug. If `rd` really saves me time, then I'd spent some of that saved time in runtime-presence-verification.

Comment: Downside of this approach: it will create a window for cmd.exe which will stop your full-screen window from remaining visible, as it will be minimized.

Comment: *"too simple to ignore"* - Actually, it's so simple that it should be ignored, like literally always. An implementation that's unable to report the outcome of an operation is just useless. The return value of [`system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) is entirely meaningless.